# error: cannot convert 'std::optional<int>' to 'const int' in initialization

Tags: c++, fold, std-ranges, c++23, stdoptional

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    const int n = ranges::fold_left_first(v | views::transform([](int i){return i*i;}), plus<int>())
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using g++14.

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:10:42: error: cannot convert 'std::optional<int>' to 'const int' in initialization
   10 |     const int n = ranges::fold_left_first(v | views::transform([](int i){return i*i;}), plus<int>())
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                          |
      |                                          std::optional<int>
```

Comment: `ranges::fold_left_first` returns `std::optional`.

Comment: You can access the optional either with it's member functions `has_value()` / `value()` or using pointer syntax: `if(v) { n = *v;}`

Comment: You can use `auto result`. Then you can print the type of result using `typeid(result).name()`, based on that, you can handle it (call `has_value()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `ranges::fold_left_first` returns `std::optional<int>` rather then `int`:

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left_first

Here's the corrected code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    std::optional<int> result = ranges::fold_left_first(v | views::transform([](int i) { return i * i; }), plus<>());

    // Check if the result has a value and use it
    if (result.has_value()) {
        const int n = result.value();
        cout << "The sum of the squares is: " << n << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "The vector is empty." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```